# AWS Lambda - How to change the handler value

Tags: aws-lambda

Just started learning how to use AWS Lambda to put my Python codes up and I've come across an issue that is making me question my sanity. In all videos, tutorials, and forums on the subject, people seem to have an entry field to modify the name of the lambda handler. This option appears nowhere on my lambda configuration page. My code does run if I use the default naming of a "lambda_function" file and a "lambda_handler" main function inside it, but nowhere do I see an option to specify my own names.

The reason I want to specify my own names is that I am trying to be able to import user-created modules and it seems the only way to do that is to modify the handler to specify a subfolder as documented [here](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/06a64ba80cf3fe886053f0ca6d375bc0) (just putting `from modulename import function, class` or whatever in the main handler_function file does not appear to work.

Thanks all for all the help !!

Comment: OMG. Just scroll down! There's a bunch of settings below the code on the Lambda function home page. When you're on the code page, just keep scrolling down to below the code! Because scrolling when you get to the code block starts to scroll the code window instead of the page this has the effect of hiding the additional settings!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change your lambda handler name.

Configuration -> Basic setting -> Handler info

You can find below Tags

See this screenshot :
[image]

For latest update remove basic setting of lambda so follow this :

1. Click on layer as show below in image
2. Check Run time setting and edit it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, I'm guessing as late as last year it was in a different place on the screen and all the documentation I was finding still showed it there. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to upvote and accept answer. Happy Coding :) @r_A_r

Comment: This option seems to be removed in the current iteration

Comment: @neilharia7 you can do. Updated answer for latest setting.

Comment: Upvote on question too @neilharia7

Answer (score 1):

They have changed the AWS Lambda UI again since the last answer. Now the setting is in:

**Code --> Runtime settings --> Handler info (click Edit)**

[image]